# Stored Procedure Date appears long date

Tags: date, stored-procedures

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_My_Procedured]
AS
BEGIN  
SELECT Mission_Time

FROM Mission_Table

WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE

cast(getdate() as Date)=Mission_Time
END
```

When i run SP_My_Procedured,

I see Mission_Time **as**

```
"2014-01-04 08:35:05.510"
"2014-01-03 10:49:00.697"
```

But ı want to see like below,

```
"2014-01-04"
"2014-01-03"
```

So how can i do this in stored procedure by select ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the value in the `SELECT` list to `Date`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_My_Procedured]
AS
BEGIN  
   SELECT 
       Mission_Time = cast(Mission_Time as Date)
   FROM 
       Mission_Table (NOLOCK)
   WHERE
       cast(Mission_Time as Date) = cast(getdate() as Date)
END
```

[BTW: there are dangers to using `NO LOCK`]
[Also, casting the column to date may not be necessary if it is already of type Date (you don't specify its type). Doing so may result in an appropriate index not being used]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), 'date', 120) AS MissionTime
```

For more date formats check [this](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)